# $E(X_1X_2)=\frac{7}{3}$, $E(X_1)=\frac{3}{2}$.Find the joint distribution of $X_1,X_2$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

> $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed (not necessarily independent) random variables taking values in $ \left\{ 1,2 \right\}$. Given, $E(X_1X_2)=\frac{7}{3}$, $E(X_1)=\frac{3}{2}$.Find the joint distribution of $X_1,X_2$.

Clearly , if we assume that $P[X_1=1]=a=1-P[X_1=2]$, then we get $a=\frac{1}{2}$ from $E(X_1)=\frac{3}{2}$
As $X_2$ is identically distributed as $X_1$ , we also get the distribution of $X_2$.
But how to get the joint pmf? They are not independent.
Help!

Comment: -what values can $X_1X_2@ take? Can you calculate the respective probabilities?

Comment: $X_1X_2$ takes values $1,2,4$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}$ respectively?

Comment: @Lengen Killer That comment from Sabyasachi Basu was a hint for you. Do you need a further hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$P(X_1,X_2=1,1)=a$$
$$P(X_1,X_2=1,2)=P(X_1,X_2=2,1)=b$$
$$P(X_1,X_2=2,2)=c$$
Then the following system of equations holds:
$$a+2b+c=1$$
$$a+b+2(b+c)=\frac32=E(X_1)$$
$$a+2(2b)+4c=\frac73=E(X_1X_2)$$
Solving gives $a,b,c=\frac13,\frac16,\frac13$, which immediately leads to the joint pmf.

Comment: Then we are not getting $P[X_1=1]+P[X_1=2]=1$

Comment: @LegendKiller Computing the marginal distribution for $X_1$ requires summing over all $X_2$ values. Thus $P(X_1=1)=P(X_1,X_2=1,1)+P(X_1,X_2=1,2)=\frac13+\frac16=\frac12$. Similarly $P(X_1=2)=\frac12$.

Comment: yes, understood